# how to send a list of popular and hot ranking books from back end using only one query in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend

Consider Schema for records:

```
title: String,
author_name: String,
pub_date: Date,
rating: Number,
ratingCount: Number
```

Now, I have route path **/books** which sends list of popular and hot ranking book to  the front end and I am calculating score for popular books using bayson avg and for hot ranking some other algo.

I am thinking of computing score at the time of sending but the problem is I want to do all of it in one mongodb query(compute two of type of score and sort one list according to one and other list on another). I have tried using aggregate and it seems perfect fit for my requirement but I haven't been able to form two separate list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like in following link this for expected results.

[Facet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-facet)